# What happens when we see "Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but..."

Tags: support, down-votes, new-users

When casting a down-vote with less than 125 rep you will get the message

> Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do
>   not change the publicly displayed post score.

I am curious as to:

- Recorded on the relevant question / answer and/or on my account?
- Will it become publicly visible retroactively after the voter reaches the 125 rep?
- If not publicly visible, is it visible to a limited user group? If yes, which group, how, what is done with it?

Comment: Flagging my own question as duplicate. I did not search the network wide [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Turns out it is [covered there quite well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288051/what-happens-with-votes-cast-with-rep-15-exactly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I cannot close my own question as duplicate, because the other question I found is not on this site but on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Keeping the question to allow others to find this answer that I found here:
[What happens with votes cast with rep < 15 exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288051/what-happens-with-votes-cast-with-rep-15-exactly)

> > What does recorded mean exactly?
>
> Recorded in database, separate table. (Not along with ordinary votes) 
>   It can be queried via SEDE, as explained [in this other answer I
>   wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247419/152859).
>
> > Can the owner of the up-voted question/answer see in any kind, that he/she got my up-vote?
>
> No, this is not possible.
>
> > Does he/she get rep for this?
>
> No, no reputation is gained to any side.
>
> > What happens with these votes, if I reach the 15 rep? Will they take effect subsequently?
>
> As explained in the answers to [this other
>   question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285181/once-i-reach-15-reputation-will-my-old-votes-be-taken-into-account),
>   nothing happens to those votes, and they don't have subsequent effect,
>   you'll have to vote again.
>
> > Or are they just recorded for my "vote-history"?
>
> No, they are not part of the votes tab in the profile.

Comment: Eh. I think we can give it a pass. Don't forget to select this as a correct answer when you can

Comment: I will keep this as top one yes: raising awareness of the network wide meta platform added the most value for me. thanks for sharing 

Answer (score 4):

Yes, no and there's no visibility of it.

There's super limited cases where mods can see who voted on a post anyway.

So if you want it up voted, you can upvote it again  I'm told the results of new user upvotes are stored but even as a mod, I don't think there's any visibility or practical value in them

Comment: Thanks for your experience on this. This this confuses me: why store something that is not used?

Comment: @PaulvanLeeuwen - In a single word.  **Inclusiveness**

Comment: Actually, no idea. Statistics I guess

Comment: bad rule. people having high reputations make such rule in their own favor to undermine the rights of people having less reputations.

Comment: @V S Rawat, you have no rights on a website you do not own. The term would be "privilege".